# Where does request logging belong?

Tags: logging, architecture

Should logging logic be put in the view layer or the service layer?

I'm thinking service layer makes more sense since it is a common layer underlying multiple different views (http, rpc, etc). If logging was done in the view layer, then it would have to be implemented for each different view.

But on the other hand, if all the logging logic is in the service layer, there will be nothing to log incoming requests and failures at the view level (for example JWT authentication failures, which examine the HTTP request headers before the request ever reaches the service).

Where should logging take place?

Comment: Why not both?  Let application configuration settings determine which logging to enable/disable.  Any decent logging framework is going to have such configuration options.

Comment: I don't know, I kind of like the idea of having logging logic centralized in one location. Also if the logging is implemented as a gateway service the view should (ideally) have no knowledge of it. If I were to start logging in the view layer, it would need to have knowledge of this third party logging server and know how to communicate with it.

Comment: The application layer doesn't need knowledge of that dependency at all.  The specifics may differ between technologies, but in general I would have a logging interface in my domain to which all components can log.  My dependency inversion would provide the implementation for that interface, unknown to any given component using the interface.  I guess if you arbitrarily want to log in only one place, then you'd have to pick a place for that.  But application code and service code do very different things and operate on very different data, personally I'd want the option to log both.

Comment: That's a good point. I'm just worried about making the view smarter than it needs to be by putting too much logic into it when really what I want is for it to be as dumb as possible. It somehow seems wrong to me to have the view layer firing off http requests to other servers. Perhaps one solution could be to log the error in the request context and then passing that into the service where it gets logged...

Answer (score 0):

Logging is a cross-cutting concern, which means it takes place in many layers (similar to authentication). So, if you feel you need to log from e.g. the presentation layer - you just do it by using a common interface, which is independent from the actual implementation. For example, in Java, we often use `slf4j`, which is a facade to the underlying logger implementation. However, you are right that it's generally a good idea to have one place which uses that logging facade. Usually you log mostly exceptions, warnings etc, so you log them in a component responsible for handling exceptions. In `Spring`, often the `@ControllerAdvice` annotation is used to tag such a component (it gives you the options to intercept all controller calls and e.g. handle your exceptions in a central place). The other option is to use `AOP` programming (e.g. `AspectJ`) to log all methods/exceptions (but it doesn't allow you to configure which messages to log during runtime of the adviced join point). You can also use events, which is a very elegant solution, because everything your code does is to raise meaningful events, which will be handled somewhere else (e.g. by a component responsible for logging all events).

So, to sum it up - logging can happen in every layer, but you should avoid scatterring your `logger.log()` calls everywhere in your code and use some more structured approach (central exception handling class, aop or events) instead.

BTW, the question is not related to DDD, so I think you should remove domain-driven-design tag.

Comment: I removed the DDD tag